# How can I simplify retrieving related tables in a Laravel database using Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

I just wanted to know, if there is any simpler way to get an array of the related tables in my database. I think there is a simpler way, than I did it.

I have 2 tables.

**[Tags]**

- ID
- Name
- Category_ID

**[Categories]**

- ID
- Name

I want to get an array like this:

array(
'Category1' => [
'tag1',
'tag2',
'tag3'
],
'Category2' => [
'tag1',
'tag2',
'.......'
]
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Laravel's Eloquent, you can use model relationships to simplify. I assume you have defined the Eloquent models for each table.

```
use App\Models\Category;

$categories = Category::with('tags')->get();

$result = [];

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $result[$category->name] = $category->tags->pluck('name')->toArray();
}
```

Don't forget to define the relationships, in category model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::class);
    }
}
```

and in the Tag model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tysm! This works perfectly.